# how to redirect on another page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

http://example.com/example/education_detail.php?uid=example@example.com; i want to redirect this url to another page but same url showing browser link bar so how can i change url. my url code `window.location.href="education_detail.php?uid=<?php echo htmlentities($user_id);?>";`

Backend Code

```
<?php
        if(empty($amount)){
            $error[] =  "Please Enter Expected Amount";
        }
        elseif(empty($cheque_name)){
            $error[] =  "Please Enter Issue Cheque in Favour of";
        }
        if (count($error)) {
            echo "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'> ";
            echo implode('<br>', $error);
            echo "</i>";
        }
        else{
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE education SET amount='$amount', cheque_name='$cheque_name', purpose_amount='$purpose_amount', date='$date' WHERE id='$apply_id'")or die("Could not insert data: " .mysqli_error($conn));
                echo 1;
        }
    ?>
```

below is ajax Jquery code

```
$('.btn_education_step5').click(function(){            
    var formdata=new FormData($('#education_step5')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'includes/backend_education_amount.php',
            method: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data : formdata,
            success:function(answer_from_actionpage){
                if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){
                    window.location.href="education_detail.php?uid=<?php echo htmlentities($user_id);?>";                   
                }else{
                    $('.error').html(answer_from_actionpage);
                }
            }           
        })
});
```

Comment: Do the redirect in the PHP instead of returning `echo 1` use `header("Location: education_detail.php?uid=$user_id");`

Comment: and what can i do in  success:function(answer_from_actionpage){ ..}.

Comment: Just do what is in the else

Comment: Doing the redirect in PHP won't work for his purposes because he is using an AJAX call, not a regular form submit.

Answer (score 1):

First confirm your `echo htmlentities($user_id);` is print different user_id.

Comment: Means? This `$user_id` variable not having any value?

Comment: If it is not print different user_id then how it will redirect to other page with differnt user_id.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the entire code of the backend script it is hard to determine what is wrong. It looks like you might be echoing back more than just the "1" response and so your success handler is not correctly seeing the response you want.

In your backend script when you echo "1" be sure to stop the script from executing at that point if anything below that code has any output like HTML or other PHP logic. I would change your echo to a die command to stop script execution and return a 1:

```
die(1);
```